# Is $k_1s_1(t)$ a solution to the nonlinear ODE?

Tags: calculus

Consider the following nonlinear ODE:

$$m\ddot s=s-s^2$$

Suppose $s_1(t)$ and $s_2(t)$ are solutions and $k_1$ and $k_2$ are constants. Is $k_1s_1(t)$ a solution?

How would one check this?

Also, the answer says that in general superposition does not hold for nonlinear ODE's. What is meant by this?

Comment: Try replacing $s$ in both sides of the ODE by $k_1s_1$. You will need to figure out $(k_1s_1) $ double dot, etc.

Comment: To say that superposition does not hold means that there exists at least one pair of solutions to the ODE whose sum is not a solution of the ODE.

Comment: Compare this behaviour with the behaviour of solutions of linear ODEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k_1s_1(t)$ is not solution (of course with $k_1\neq 1$ and $k_1\neq 0$).

To check it, put it into the ODE and obseve if it agrees or not. :

$m(k_1s_1)''\neq (k_1s_1)-(k_1s_1)^2$ because $ms_1''\neq s_1-k_1s_1^2$ , since $s_1''= s_1-s_1^2$. So, it doesn't agree.

Superposition does not hold for nonlinear ODE's means that the linear combination of particular solutions is not solution of the ODE.

For example $k_1s_1(t)+k_2s_2(t)$ is not solution of the ODE. Put it into the ODE and observe that it doesn't agree.